# Changing the array description text without editing plugin's core files with a filter function in wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I have checked many questions from this forum about this solution, but I could not get it at all. I'm learning how to overwrite some text from existing array in plugin without editing it's core files so I will not loose my changes when the core plugin is updated in wordpress.

What I have is this code right from the plugin. There is one string which I can not translate from po.edit. Please get that I'm just learning this solution so I do not know how to really get it at all so that's why I'm asking for your advice.

Core code

```
/**
     * Initialize integration settings form fields.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function init_form_fields() {
        $this->form_fields = array(
            'authorization'   => array(
                'title' => __( 'Authorization', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
                'type'  => 'google_calendar_authorization',
            ),
            'testing'         => array(
                'title'       => __( 'Connect with a custom Google Calendar App', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
                'type'        => 'title',
                'description' => 'Enter the credentials below to use a custom Google Calendar API app. Disconnect existing connection to enter credentials.',
            ),
            'client_id'       => array(
                'title'       => __( 'Client ID', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
                'type'        => 'text',
                'description' => __( 'Enter the Google Client ID associated with your Calendar API app.', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
                'disabled'    => $this->is_using_wooconnect_method(),
                'desc_tip'    => true,
                'default'     => '',
            ),
            'client_secret'   => array(
                'title'       => __( 'Client Secret', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
                'type'        => 'text',
                'description' => __( 'Enter the Google Client Secret associated with your Calendar API app.', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
                'disabled'    => $this->is_using_wooconnect_method(),
                'desc_tip'    => true,
                'default'     => '',
            ),
            'custom_authorization'   => array(
                'title' => __( 'Authorization', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
                'type'  => 'custom_google_calendar_authorization',
            ),
            'calendar_connection_settings' => array(
                'title'         => __( 'Connected Calendar Settings', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
                'type'          => 'title',
                'display_check' => array( $this, 'display_connection_settings' ),
            ),
            'calendar_id'       => array(
                'title'         => __( 'Calendar', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
                'type'          => 'select',
                'description'   => __( 'Select your Calendar.', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
                'desc_tip'      => true,
                'default'       => '',
                'options'       => $this->get_calendar_list_options(),
                'display_check' => array( $this, 'display_connection_settings' ),
            ),
            'sync_preference'   => array(
                'type'          => 'select',
                'title'         => __( 'Sync Preference', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
                'options'       => array(
                    'both_ways' => __( 'Sync both ways - between Store and Google', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
                    'one_way'   => __( 'Sync one way - from Store to Google', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
                ),
                'description'   => __( 'Manage the sync flow between your Store calendar and Google calendar.', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
                'desc_tip'      => true,
                'default'       => 'one_way',
                'display_check' => array( $this, 'display_connection_settings' ),
            ),
            'debug'           => array(
                'title'       => __( 'Debug Log', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
                'type'        => 'checkbox',
                'label'       => __( 'Enable logging', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
                'default'     => 'no',
                /* translators: 1: log file path */
                'description' => sprintf( __( 'Log Google Calendar events, such as API requests, inside %s', 'woocommerce-bookings' ), '<code>woocommerce/logs/' . $this->id . '-' . sanitize_file_name( wp_hash( $this->id ) ) . '.txt</code>' ),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Generate Settings HTML.
     *
     * Extends base class html generation to add 'display_check' parameter to each
     * field. 'display_check', is a callable that enables/disables the display of
     * the field.
     *
     * @param array $form_fields (default: array()) Array of form fields.
     * @param bool  $echo Echo or return.
     * @return string the html for the settings
     * @since  1.15.0
     */
    public function generate_settings_html( $form_fields = array(), $echo = true ) {
        if ( empty( $form_fields ) ) {
            $form_fields = $this->get_form_fields();
        }
        foreach ( $form_fields as $index => $field ) {
            // Delete fields if they have an "enable_check" function that returns false.
            if ( isset( $field['display_check'] ) && ! call_user_func( $field['display_check'] ) ) {
                unset( $form_fields[ $index ] );
            }
        }
        return parent::generate_settings_html( $form_fields, $echo );
    }
```

Now there is a testing array in the core code where I need to change its description

```
'testing'         => array(
                'title'       => __( 'Connect with a custom Google Calendar App', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
                'type'        => 'title',
                'description' => 'Enter the credentials below to use a custom Google Calendar API app. Disconnect existing connection to enter credentials.',
            ),
```

I have tried this but I think its not the right solution for my problem because I can not get it work.

```
add_filter( 'init_form_fields', 'replace_text', 11, 2 );

function replace_text( $form_fields ) {
    $form_fields = array(
   'testing'=> array(
   'title'=> __( 'Connect with a custom Google Calendar App', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
   'type'=> 'title',
   'description' => 'New description',
            ),
); 
    return $form_fields;
}
```

Could you please help me to find a right solution. Thank you